# how can I encode JWT with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, jwt

this is my payload

```
field1=valueField1&field2=valueField2&request=jwtEncodedRequest
```

Where `jwtEncodedRequest` is indeed a request encoded via jwt.

currently I'm using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) to create an encoded request.

is it possible automatize this with jmeter?

Comment: can you give more details on how you currently generate the token in jwt.io and show you request in JMeter ? thanks

Comment: sorry for delay ... the request looks like this: HEADER -> `{
  "alg": "RS256", "fielda":"fieldValue"}` PAYLOAD -> `{"fieldPayload1":"fieldPayloadValue1", "fieldPayload2":"fieldPayloadValue2", "fieldPayload3":"fieldPayloadValue3", "fieldPayload4":"fieldPayloadValue4"}` VERIFY SIGNATURE --> `(SECRET KEY)`

Answer (score 2):

1. Add [Apache Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/download.cgi) jar to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan
4. Put the following code to "Script" area:

   ```
   @Grab(group='io.jsonwebtoken', module='jjwt', version='0.9.1')

   import io.jsonwebtoken.*

   import java.security.PrivateKey
   import java.util.Base64
   import java.util.Base64.Decoder

   import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

   import java.security.interfaces.ECPrivateKey
   import java.security.KeyFactory
   import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
   import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec

   // Generating Tokens for API Requests
   // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests

   def exp = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + 1200).intValue()
   //20 minutes from now

   //JWT Payload (update with your Issuer ID)
   String jsonString = """{"iss":"57246542-96fe-1a63-e053-0824d011072a","exp":${exp},"aud":"appstoreconnect-v1"}""";

   //Content of the AuthKey_2X9R4HXF34.p8
   /* 
   -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
   MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQg74+aaeYnqEIewDn8
   Xh0rQXaQqAHSLGDyL9fV0p1hhxGgCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCHOTEUjCMi4Vt7JGZ
   jsRP1zF765oerCqfvHZYGqSeJl8AmK0awchcqAaMlw7hROoA2MToqx+llo2p9lZC
   QYbeerau
   -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
   */

   //Key concatenated in a single line
   //You better not hard code this key
   def base64EncodedPrivateKey = "MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQg74+aaeYnqEIewDn8Xh0rQXaQqAHSLGDyL9fV0p1hhxGgCgYIKoZIzj0DAQehRANCHOTEUjCMi4Vt7JGZjsRP1zF765oerCqfvHZYGqSeJl8AmK0awchcqAaMlw7hROoA2MToqx+llo2p9lZCQYbeerau"

   ECPrivateKey signingKey
   Base64.Decoder dec= Base64.getDecoder();
   keyBytes = dec.decode(base64EncodedPrivateKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));

   PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
   KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
   signingKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

   //Notice you don't need to encode the header nor the payload
   String jwtToken = Jwts.builder()
   //JWT Header
           .setHeaderParam("typ","JWT")
           .setHeaderParam("alg","ES256")
           .setHeaderParam("kid","2X9R4HXF34") //UPDATE with your Key Identifier
           .setPayload(jsonString)
           .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES256, signingKey)
           .compact();

   log.info(jwtToken)
   ```
5. You should see JWT token printed to *jmeter.log* file:

   [image]

More information:

- [JSON Web Token Quickstart](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#quickstart)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Hi guy,
I run this code and get the error in macOS bellow. Please help me try to fix it, Thanks!
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jwts for class: Script1

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

- Use a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) with Groovy
- Compute token using this [java library](https://github.com/auth0)
- Add the above library to jmeter/lib folder